# Как переключиться на frame в python pyppeteer?

Tags: python

Пишу автоматизацию на Pyppeteer, нужно переключиться на frame, но у самого фрейма из атрибьютов только src который имеет всегда одинаковое начало (ссылка на каптчу)

```
[
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB9012B820>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB901DD160>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB92A0DFD0>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB92A0DF40>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB92A263D0>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB92A26580>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB92A26F10>,
 <pyppeteer.frame_manager.Frame object at 0x000001DB92A3A9D0>
]
```

Имеется вот такой список фреймов, каким образом можно получить его атрибью src и если он тот что нужен, переключиться на него и кликнуть на кнопку внутри него? Искал в инете, но все фиксы работают на js, а в py перевести у меня их не получается.